# conceptual data model for B2D(eveloper) SaaS platform

Tags: data-modeling, saas, datamodel

I am just starting to work on the conceptual data model for a SaaS B2D(eveloper) platform. The platform allows anonymous use through the downloading of an sdk and the creation of anonymous API keys. We intuitively 'anthropomorphise' our developers as human agents who make rational decisions about interacting with the platform and ultimately registering/paying but at the top of the funnel there may be friendly/unfriendly/fake/bot agents at play.  We can track IP addresses but this is a very imperfect mechanism and there may well be many to many use of api keys by developers.  Developers can also 'visit' the site socially.

Does anyone have any thoughts/resources about how I might get started with the scope and structure of the conceptual data model?  Anyone done this kind of thing already?

This is a pretty nuanced problem so couldn't find anything specifically on it. Came across user 'collusion' but most standard SaaS metrics resources do not deal with this issue.